Keycloak using firebase as identity provider
Using firebase as authentication provider and it works, using this url :
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=XXXXX
once i try to configure this as an identity provider on keycloak, the
Authorization URL *
Token URL *

it generates a url of the client that responds 404 when you try to use it.
how to configure the keycloak using firebase as identity provider ?

Were you able to find a solution?

There's no out-of-the-box provider for keycloak built into Firebase. So if you want to allow users to sign in to your Firebase-backed app with Keycloak, you'll have to implement your own provider and/or search if somebody already implemented such a provider.
